# Is it acceptable for user agents to modify cookies other than by instruction from the server?

Tags: http, cookies

Using javascript or in a native iOS App it is possible to read and modify cookies.

The server generally sets these, but if both the server and the client modifies the values then it becomes a global shared mutable state across systems.

This feels bad.

In the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) it does not mention user agents modifying cookies other than by predefined rules (e.g. Honoring cookie expiry).  It also says in the summary about cookies:

> … These header fields can be used by HTTP **servers to store state at HTTP user agents**

However it does not actually prohibit or explicitly advise against clients modifying cookies.

- Is it acceptable to modify cookies on a user agent?
- Are there any references or guidelines on this matter?

Comment: Once a piece of information leaves your servers and gets to your users, it's completely out of your control. So when you do get back a cookie from the user, treat it with a grain of salt.... or maybe 100 grains ;)

Comment: ...but *why* would you modify a cookie? In the end it's just a snippet of data sent by the server. You can do whatever you like with it, send it back, ignore it, scramble it. Whatever. It's just pointless.

Comment: @arnaud - (a while ago) I supported a website that allowed the user to modify the font-size for viewing through a javascript widget that set/modified a cookie value to maintain consistency during the session.

Comment: @HorusKol well, you "can" do that. But ideally, if it's just a local setting, you're better off using `localstorage` since it doesn't need to be sent to the server. And if it's user settings that should be saved server-side, better make a real request out of it. ...IMHO, using cookies for such things is just weird.

Comment: @arnaud well, this was before local storage... there are probably still use cases out there, even if you think its "weird".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to think of it:

It is impossible for the server to directly set a cookie. The server sends an HTTP header, which *tells* the client to set a cookie. It's the same way with JavaScript or hand-editing, because it is *assumed* that if the client can change the cookie, the server can't complain (unless the request is malicious).

EU law also explicitly gives the client the right to refuse cookies.

HTTP is stateless, and the cookie *isn't part of the protocol itself*. This isn't like whether the server should return a proper status code.

---

Maybe I'm not fully understanding your question, but why does it matter? It's common, accepted practice anyway. [Googling "client modify cookie"](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=standard+practice+for+client+modifying+cookie&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#q=client+modify+cookie) returns nothing against it.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Implementation):

> Although cookies are usually set by the web server, they can also be set by the client using a scripting language such as JavaScript (provided the cookie's HttpOnly flag is not set).

Then skip down a bit:

> #### HttpOnly cookie
>
> HttpOnly cookies can only be used when transmitted via HTTP (or HTTPS). They are not accessible through non-HTTP APIs such as JavaScript. This restriction eliminates the threat of cookie theft via cross-site scripting (XSS), while leaving the threats of cross-site tracing (XCT) and cross-site request forgery (CSRF) intact.

---

Therefore, we can deduce that the appropriate question isn't whether it's acceptable, but whether we [can](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/cookie).

Comment: Ok I guess a better question might be *why* you would want to do it? If it is to store state it's better doing it separately since it makes the requests larger.  If it's to send data to the server, it is better using other headers that the server can't modify itself?

Comment: @Robert This might be suited to a new thread, but I'll continue anyway. Once a cookie is set it is persistent until it expires. One example: the server stores associated data (e.g. login user) with a session cookie, which is a unique identifier. I can't think of a simpler way to keep someone logged in. 

[Here's Google's cookie policy](https://www.google.com/policies/technologies/cookies/).

What do you mean by *doing it separately*?

Comment: Yes, this may be better in another thread.  I was looking for examples where the client would want to set the state not the server.  If the client was using the cookies just as storage it would be better off storing it in local storage.  Your answer is useful so I am just going to accept.